# Garment Cropping from mannequin

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have two images – mannequin **with** and **without** garment.

Please refer sample images below. Ignore the jewels, footwear on the mannequin, imagine the second mannequin has **only dress**.

[image] 
[image]

I want to **extract** only the **garment** from the two images for further processing.

The complexity is that there is **slight displacement** in the position of camera when taking the two pictures. Due to this simple subtraction to generate the garment mask will not work.

**Can anyone tell me how to handle it?**

I think I need to do **registration** between the two images so that I can extract only the garment from the image?

Any references to blogs, articles and codes is highly appreciated.

--
Thanks

Comment: That mannequin has plenty of skin. May be you can get a skin probability matrix from the first image, correlate and subtract from the second image and just knock off the disconnected components. (Just and idea, though).

Answer (score 2):

### Idea

This is an idea of how you could do it, I haven't tested it but my gut tells me it might work. I'm assuming that there will be slight differences in the pose of the manequin as well as the camera attitude.

Let the original image be `A`, and the clothed image be `B`.

Take the difference `D = |A - B|`, apply a median filter that is proportional to the largest deviation you expect from pose and camera attitude error: `Dmedian = Median(D, kernelsize)`.

Quantize `Dmedian` into a binary mask `Dmask = Q(Dmedian, threshold)` using appropriate threshold values to obtain an **approximate** mask for the garment (this will be smaller than the garment itself due to the median filter). Reject any shapes in `Dmedian` that have too small area by setting their pixels to 0.

Expand the shape(s) in `Dmask` proportionally to the size of the median kernel into `Emask=expand(Dmask, k*kernelsize)`. Then construct the difference in the masks `Fmask=|Dmask - Emask|` which now contains areas of pixels where the garment edge is expected to be. For every pixel in `Fmask` which is in this area, find the correlation `Cxy` between `A` and `B` using a small neighbourhood, store the correlations into an image `C=1.0 - Corr(A,B, Fmask, n)`.

Your final garment mask will be `M=C+Dmask`.

### Explanation

Since your image has nice and continuous swatches of colour, the difference between the two similar images will be thin lines and small gradients where the pose and camera attitude is different. When taking a median filter of the difference image over a sufficiently large kernel, these lines will be removed because they are in a minority of the pixels.

The garment on the other hand will (hopefully) have a significant difference from the colors in the unclothed version. And will generate a bigger difference. Thresholding the difference after the median filter should give you a rough mask of the garment that is undersized dues to some of the pixels on the edge being rejected due to their median values being too low. You could stop here if the approximation is good enough for you.

By expanding the mask we obtained above we get a probable region for the "true" edge. The above process has served to narrow our search region for the true edge considerably and we can apply a more costly correlation search between the images along this edge to find where the garment is. High correlation means no carment and low correlation means garment.

We use the inverted correlation as an alpha value together with the initially smaller mask to obtain a alpha valued mask of the garment that can be used for extracting it.

### Clarification

Expand: What I mean by "expanding the mask" is to find the contour of the mask region and outsetting/growing/enlarging it to make it larger.

`Corr(A,B,Fmask,n)`: Is just an arbitrarily chosen correlation function that gives correlation between pixels in `A` and `B` that are selected by the mask `Fmask` using a region of size `n`. The function returns `1.0` for perfect match and `0.0` for anti-match for each pixel tested. A good function is this pseudocode:

```
foreach px_pos in Fmask where Fmask[px_pos] == 1
  Ap = subregion(A, px_pos, size) - mean(mean(A));
  Bp = subregion(B, px_pos, size) - mean(mean(B))
  Cxy = sum(sum(Ap .* Bp))*sum(sum(Ap .* Bp)) / (sum(sum(Ap.*Ap))*sum(sum(Bp.*Bp)))
  C[px_pos] = 1.0 - Cxy;
end
```

where `subregion` selects a region of size `size` around the pixel with position `px_pos`.
You can see that if `Ap == Bp` then `Cxy=1`

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I will try out and update you on the quality of the results.

Comment: You can also allow the correlation search to look for correlations in a surrounding pixel region to adjust for variations in camera attitude and pose better. An approach similar to that used in DIC would work I guess.

Comment: :: Can you describe what is "expand"? And Corr(A, B, Fmask, n)? .. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have completed till expand step.. I am varying the threshold to suit different type of garments and also the kernel size of median blur.. I will do the correlation step tomorrow.. Is it possible to share the code with me if you have already done something similar...

Comment: The kernelsize should be large enough so you don't get anything except the garment and then the expansion should be so big that you get the garment edge and some extra. (i.e. garment edge should be inside the expanded area).
Sorry, I don't have any code for this that I am able to share, I've done image segment correlation but I'm not at allowed to share that.
_Could you show what it looks like after median and threshold, I'm curious_

Comment: :: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1dwtgx4kdxppxmk/Extraction.rar look at the results in the link and share your comments. Lighting is one another problem.. Can you suggest anything for that

Comment: B :: Did you get a chance to look at the results

Comment: I finally did, that's interesting some of them seem to have good results others have varying degrees of success. I see one of them where the whole arm is still in there. My guess is the arm moved significantly while putting on the sweater.

I would try a larger median kernel and it'd have been interesting to see the difference images too. Also I believe your correlation search isn't doing very well.

Comment: :: Thanks for the reply. Yes, you are right, my correlation search is not working. It is more or less converging to the median filter mask. Any inputs for further improvements or trials you have in mind?

Comment: Difficult for me to give any more help without having everything at hand and I currently don't have time to do this (even though it seems interesting). Just try to make sure the pose doesn't change while you dress the manequin and play with the filter sizes and make sure the correlation search does something usefull (search the surrounding and take the max correlation found)